# How to get an image in the top right corner of my form

Tags: html, css, forms, image

I'm trying to get a logo in the top right corner of my form but I can't figure out how to set that in my css.

My HTML:

```
{% block body %}

<form action="{{ url_for('my_form') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Gasten registratie</h1> 
        <p>Vul dit formulier in om te registreren</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="First-Name"><b>Voornaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="First-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw voornaam in" name="Voornaam" required>

        <label for="Last-Name"><b>Achternaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Last-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw achternaam in" name="Achternaam" required>


        <label for="Company-name"><b>Bedrijfsnaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Company-name" placeholder="Vul hier uw bedrijfsnaam in" name="Bedrijfsnaam" required>


        <label for="Date"><b>Datum</b></label>
        <input type="date" id="Date" placeholder="Selecteer de Datum" name="Datum" required />
        <hr>


        <p>In het kader van onze ISAE certificering registreren wij uw gegevens.</p>
        <p>Wij verwerken uw gegevens volgends de regels van het AVG.</p>
        <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Registreren</button>
    </div>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My CSS:

```
h1{text-align: left;}


* {box-sizing: border-box}


/* Add padding to containers */
.container {

    background-image: url("inconto.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top, right;
    background-size: 45px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    max-width: 750px;
    max-height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;


}

.Fist-Name {font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;}

.Last-Name {font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;}

.Company-name {font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;}


/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=date] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=date]:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline: none;
}

/* Overwrite default styles of hr */
hr {
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/register button */
.registerbtn {
    background-color: #6a0dad;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.registerbtn:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

I'm trying to get the picture in the container in the right top within the form at the same height as the first header "Gasten Registratie" in the form. For illustrative support I will attach a picture of the form. If someone could help me that would be great.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd find it easier using an `<img>` tag over a `background-image` :)

Comment: You should try inspecting your page, and see if the `.container` div is the appropriate size. Also `.First-Name` class is misspelled.

Comment: Your `background-position: top, right;` CSS is incorrect. It should be `background-position: top right;`. This should move it to the top, right corner and have it padded by 16 pixels.

Comment: so put the image in the html file?